# Why am I forbidden from creating a checkout using the Shopify API Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Is any using the [Shopify API rub gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api)? I'm building a headless storefront where few things not working. I can fetch Products but cannot create a checkout so I can add items to cart.

Ruby: 2.7.0
Rails: 6.0.2.1

The setup:

**config/initializers/shopify.rb:**

```rb
shop_url = "https://#{ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']}:#{ENV['SHOPIFY_PASSWORD']}@#{ENV['SHOP_NAME']}.myshopify.com"
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
ShopifyAPI::Base.api_version = ENV['STORE_API_VERSION'] # find the latest stable api_version [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/versioning)
```

The above is per docs as Im using a private app.

In a controller:

```rb
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find('12345678')
# This works fine. Now:

checkout = ShopifyAPI::Checkout.create
# <ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess: Failed.  Response code = 403.  Response message = Forbidden.>
```

The `create` I got from [their tests](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/test/checkouts_test.rb#L20) but it's "blowing up".

I tried to understand how to add items to cart and [their JS example](https://github.com/Shopify/storefront-api-examples/blob/master/react-apollo/src/App.js#L44) shows that on page load, they create a checkout then use its `id` when adding items to cart.

Though my frontend is JS, everything runs through Rails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checkout API requires your APP to be public.

In addition your app must be set as a Sales Channel ( which privates APP's can't do, that's why you need a public one ) and your products must be available to that sales channel in order to add them to the checkout.

As an alternative you can use the Storefront API https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/checkoutcreate